# Really Frustrating: validate method with callback in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback

I am having trouble with these validation and callback methods.

After saving an object, I want to update two columns of an associated model object as shown in the adjust_inventory callback method.

But, if running adjust_inventory method results in units.quantity to be < 0, I want to prevent object from being created and add the validation error.

Here is my model (UPDATED):
Note: I am using the deferred_associations gem based on this post: http://mikrobi.github.io/validating-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-with-rails-3/

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_and_belongs_to_many_with_deferred_save :units
  validate :prevent_oversell
  after_create :adjust_inventory



  def adjust_inventory
    units.each do |ad|
      if ad.quantity_sold.blank?
    ad.update_attribute(:quantity_sold, 0)
    end
      new_quant = ad.quantity-1
      new_quant_s = ad.quantity_sold+1
      ad.update_attribute(:quantity, new_quant)
      ad.update_attribute(:quantity_sold, new_quant_s)
    end
  end

  def prevent_oversell
      @arr = []
      self.units.each do |q|
        @arr << q.id
      end

      hash = @arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h,x| h[x]+=1;h}

      self.units.each do |t|
        if t.quantity < hash[t.id] 
         errors[:base] = "Your selection exceeds available inventory. Please check that your size selection matches available inventory"
      end
    end    
  end
end
```

Please help me someone!! This is driving me bonkers.

Another update: It seems as though the validation is working to prevent an order that results in quantity < 0, however, the error message is displayed even if object is created (and passes validation).

Comment: First of all, if you want to do it AFTER save then use after_save callback instead. Plus, remove please this stuff ever where `else nil end` and do it straight in `if end` block; if you want to stop all the moves after validation add false in the end of the method(to return false)

Comment: I have tried using after_save, but the :adjust_inventory method is still called. I also cleaned up the code as you suggested. I put false at the end in the each loop in prevent_oversell method also. The validation is working, but the adjust_inventory method is regardless. Thanks for your help. Also, the problem with using after_save is that the result could be to reduce quantity to < 0, after validation.

Comment: Try this version of these methods, I've tried to refactor them http://pastebin.com/bLzNb5jy And end false before last end of validation method

Comment: this still didn't work. The validation seems to be working correctly but the error message is being shown incorrectly.

Comment: As in no record is being saved to the db that results in <0 quantity. I found this post that helps to explain the solution, though: http://mikrobi.github.io/validating-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-with-rails-3/, and this gem: https://github.com/MartinKoerner/deferred_associations. Apparently associated records cannot be access until after the record is saved to the db, hence why validating the associated records, which takes place before saving, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was entirely the wrong way for doing what I was trying to do. This achieves what I want:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  validates_numericality_of :quantity, :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_and_belongs_to_many :units
  before_create :adjust_inventory
  validates_associated :units

  def adjust_inventory
    units.each do |ad|
      if ad.quantity_sold.blank?
         ad.update_attributes(quantity_sold: 0)
      end
      new_quant = ad.quantity-1
      new_quant_s = ad.quantity_sold+1
      ad.update_attributes(quantity: new_quant)
      ad.update_attributes(quantity_sold: new_quant_s)
    end
  end
end
```